# Editing actions (row actions) don't appear on swipe in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, editing, appearance, uitableviewrowaction

here is my problem:
I have an editButton and editActions for each cell

So I wanted checkboxes instead of red minuses . I've found this block of code:

```js
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
      
      // Возвращаем стиль с checkbox'ами, который мне нужен
      return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.init(rawValue: 3)!
      
   }
```

it [helped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXGR4.png) me. BUT!!1 Because of this code, rowActions stoped to appear. When I try to swipe to the left, cells just perform their segues (like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1FZx.png)). It is not normal.

Comment: There is no UITableViewCellEditingStyle with a rawValue = 3 maximum is 2. BTW It is much easier to just  `return .insert`

Comment: Okey, then why, if I return .insert, there are green pluses on the left of the cells. If I return .init(rowValue: 3), I get, checkboxes - what I want, and if I return init(rowvalue:4) or any other rowValue, I get nothing on the left of the cells??